# populate dropdown on selecting previous dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

As you can see in the JSP code below, there are 2 dropdowns : make and model. I want to select an option in make and the model dropdown should be autofilled from database with values corresponding to that make.

I'm doing this using AJAX and JSON but on selecting any value in Make, the JS to fill next dropdown is not called (alert() in JS is not called). I checked that the id's everywhere are correct but still the JS is not called. Please see why the JS file is not called and if the Servlet called is correct?

Please note: The JS file is on the JSP, and not as a seperate file.

JSP:

```
<select id = "Make" name = "make" class = "form-control" >
<option value = "" > Make < /option>
<%
for (int i = 0; i < activity.length; i++) {
%> 
<option value = "<%=activity[i][0]%>"> <%=activity[i][0]%> </option>
<%
}
%>
</select>

<select id="Model" name="model" class="form-control">
<option value="">Model</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Make').change(function(event) {
            alert("JS called.");
        var $Make=$("select#Make").val();
           $.get('Inventory_dropdown_ACT',{custucmake:$Make},function(responseJson) {
            var html;
            var $select = $('#Model');
            $.each(responseJson.arrayName, function(options) {
             html += '<option name="'+options.custucmodel+'" >'+options.custucmodel+'</option>';
            });
         $select.html(html);
        },'json');
        });
    });
```

Inventory_dropdown_ACT.java:

```
package admin.inventory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

import commons.DbCon;

public class Inventory_dropdown_ACT extends HttpServlet {

    // populate dropdown
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        JSONArray cellarray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject cellobj = null;
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        String make = request.getParameter("make");
        try {
            Connection con = DbCon.getCon("", "", "");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from ucmakemodelvariant where ucmmvmake='" + make + "'");
            while (rs.next()) {
                cellobj = new JSONObject();
                cellobj.put("custucmodel", rs.getString(4));
                cellarray.add(cellobj);
            }
            jo.put("arrayName", cellarray);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            response.getWriter().write(jo.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What can you see in the response from the server(Are you getting ny respone), I mean if you look in the network section in the browser's debug window

Comment: no response at all. nothind happens on selecting make.

Comment: is the $get() is firing at all?

Comment: No. That is what I'm saying the JS is not called. there is an alert() in JS which doesn't show up!!

Comment: have you included jquery js? please check your console in browser if page is loaded without any error and jquery is loaded

Comment: I checked that. JS is showing there.

Comment: The JS is not firing up because the 'Make' option is selected already, nothings changing when you select Make. Include `<option disabled selected value>Select </option>` as first child of `Select`.

Comment: JS fired up on changing code as said by @insomaniac. But the dropdown is still empty!

Comment: You need to fetch value of **make** in servlet using **custucmake** and not **make**, as this is what you are sending from jquery.
`String make = request.getParameter("custucmake");`

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery and Write the event listener like below and try the code inside inside

```
$(document).on('change','#Make', MakeChange);

/**
* Your function for populating the second dropdown
*
**/
function MakeChange(){
   alert("JS called.");
   var $Make=$("select#Make").val();
   $.ajax({url:'yourUrl',
           method:'GET',
           data:{yourdata},
           dataType:'json',
           success:function(response){
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
           }})
}
```

And either change the parameter in the get request in JS to `make` from `custumcake` or change the line in the server
 `request.getParameter("make");`

to

`request.getParameter("custumcake");`

Comment: YES. "JS called" showed up. Next dropdown is still empty!

Comment: `$.get('Inventory_dropdown_ACT',{custucmake:$Make},function(responseJson) {` in this line of code, custucmake is name of column in db and Make is id of dropdown. Is this correct?

Comment: You need to add a parameter 'make' instead of 'custucmake' because it is accessed from server

Comment: url : 'yourUrl' is servlet to be called?, yourdata- how do i get that from db?, in success, there is alert()-how will this fill next dropdown?

Comment: You have to code it in , I cannot copy paste all the code from the question as i am replying from my phone